# Can we install a package through a shell script?

Tags: bash, script, sudo, apt

I'm trying to write a shell script so that when I reinstall my Ubuntu again. I could just run script and retain all the packages. And I'm planning to pass password in form of argument.

My question here is how can i enter into **sudo** domain without manually entering `password`. As I'm also planning to design a UI where it can't access the terminal there.

**Ex:**

```
./recover.sh password
```

Would appriciate the response ;)

with regards

**pavan**

Comment: Giving a password to sudo in a script (along with why it's a bad idea) has been covered on askubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/470383/how-to-avoid-prompt-password-for-sudo.

Answer (score 1):

You can issue the command `apt-get install ${package_list}` and all packages in the the `package-list` variable will be installed if possible.

There are tools that will give you lists of installed packages.  You should remove any packages installed as dependencies, as well as packages installed by default.

Look at the command listed by `man -k apt`.

If you want no output execute the command `export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` before running apt-get.

Comment: No you have misunderstood my question. Here my logic is not only limited to recovery, but it is also covering **UI**. And consider you are creating a **UI** and if u link a button with your script. Then you can only pass a command like `./install.sh password `.

Comment: @Pavan It is possible to tell apt to work in an non-interactive mode.  `export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`

Comment: but how can we get **su** access to install

Comment: from an **UI**.

Comment: @Pavan look for `ask-pass`.  There are a variety of options.  Normally the UI has one already enabled.  You should be using `sudo` not `su`.

Comment: k .. my question here is `can we fit a sudo command and its password in single command line`

Comment: like **sudo apt-get update && password** which apparently `dosen't work`.

Comment: @Pavin  If `SUDO_ASKPASS` is set to a program that can provide the password, you can just do `sudo apt-get update`.  The ASKPASS program will take care of prompting you for the password and providing it `sudo`.